# pygame - problem with killing a sprite in a group

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game using pygame for a school project. I would like obstacles(in this case boxes) which get in the way of the player. The player is able to destroy the boxes which would result in another box to be spawned in a random location at the same height.

I've split the code into 3 seperate modules seperating the sprites, the main code and the settings(game variables).

main:

```
import pygame as pg 
import random 
from sprites import *
from settings import * 
import os 
import sys
import time

class Game:
    def __init__(init):#initialising the games properties(window,sound,speed,etc).
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        init.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        init.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        init.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        init.running = True
        init.font_name = pg.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
        init.data()
    def data(load):
        load.dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    def new(new):#starts the game again.
        new.score = 0 
        new.obstacles = pg.sprite.Group()
        new.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        new.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        new.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        new.player = Player(new)
        new.all_sprites.add(new.player)
        for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
            p = Platform(*plat) 
            new.all_sprites.add(p)
            new.platforms.add(p)
        for obs in OBSTACLE_LIST:
            new.obstacle = Obstacle(*obs)
            new.all_sprites.add(new.obstacle)
            new.obstacles.add(new.obstacle)

        new.run()
    def run(run):
        run.playing = True
        while run.playing:
            run.cooldown = 0
            run.clock.tick(FPS)
            run.events()
            run.update()
            run.draw()

    def update(update):
        bullet = Bullet
        #game update.
        update.all_sprites.update()
        #spawning obstacles lower half
        while len(update.obstacles) < 3:
            width = random.randrange(50, 100)
            update.obstacle = Obstacle(random.randrange(0, WIDTH - width),HEIGHT-100,100,50)
            update.obstacles.add(update.obstacle)
            update.all_sprites.add(update.obstacle)
        #spawning obstacles randomly throughout the middle half
        #spawning obstacles randomly throughout the map upper half
        #check if bullet collides with an obstacles.
        collide = pg.sprite.groupcollide(update.bullets,update.obstacles,True,False)
        if collide:

            update.obstacle.obs_health = update.obstacle.obs_health - bullet.damage
            if update.obstacle.obs_health == 0:
                update.obstacle.kill()  

        #check if player hits the sides of an obstacle.
        if update.player.velocity.x >0:#when moving right.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.obstacles,False)
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y >= collide[0].rect.centery+20:#if the player is above the platform.
                    update.player.pos.x = collide[0].rect.left - (PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
                    update.player.velocity.x = 0
                    update.player.acceleration.y = 0

        if update.player.velocity.x <0:#when moving left.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.obstacles,False)
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y >= collide[0].rect.centery:
                    update.player.pos.x = collide[0].rect.right + (PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
                    update.player.velocity.x = 0


        #check if player hits side of platforms            
        if update.player.velocity.x >0 and (update.player.velocity.y < 0):#when moving right.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.platforms,False)
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y < collide[0].rect.centery+50:#if the player is below the obstacle.
                    update.player.pos.x = collide[0].rect.left - (PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
                    update.player.velocity.x = 0

        if update.player.velocity.x <0:#when moving left.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.obstacles,False)
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y > collide[0].rect.centery:
                    update.player.pos.x = collide[0].rect.right + (PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
                    update.player.velocity.x = 0
        #check if player hits a platform while ascending:
        if update.player.velocity.y <0:#only when moving up.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.platforms,False)
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y > collide[0].rect.bottom:
                    update.player.pos.y = collide[0].rect.bottom + (PLAYER_HEIGHT/2) + PLAYER_JUMP 
                    update.player.velocity.y = 0 

        #check if a player hits a platform while falling.
        if update.player.velocity.y >0:#only while falling will this apply.
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.platforms,False)#false allows you to avoid deleting the object you jump into.    
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y < collide[0].rect.centery:#if the player is above the center of the platform.
                    update.player.pos.y = collide[0].rect.top +1
                    update.player.velocity.y = 0
            collide = pg.sprite.spritecollide(update.player,update.obstacles,False) 
            if collide:
                if update.player.pos.y < collide[0].rect.centery:
                    update.player.pos.y = collide[0].rect.top +1
                    update.player.velocity.y = 0
    #spawning obstacles randomly throughout the map upper half

    #spawning obstacles randomly throughout the middle half



    def events(events):
        events.cooldown += events.clock.get_time()
        #processes inputs.
        for event in pg.event.get():
            #check for window closing.
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:#if the 'x' button is clicked
                if events.playing:    
                    events.playing = False#stop the game loop.
                events.running = False#stop the main loop.
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    events.player.jump()
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                        events.player.bullet_list.append(events.player.shoot())
                        #print(len(events.player.bullet_list))
    def draw(draw):
        draw.screen.fill(GREY)# creates a black screen.
        draw.draw_text(str(draw.player.PLAYER_HEALTH),24,BLACK,WIDTH/32,HEIGHT /32)
        draw.all_sprites.draw(draw.screen)#draws the sprites in the group all_sprites.

        #after drawing the screen is flipped.
        pg.display.flip()
    def start_screen(start):#screen displayed when the game is started.
        start.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        start.draw_text(TITLE,48,WHITE,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT /4)
        start.draw_text("Arrows to move,UP to jump", 22,WHITE,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        start.draw_text("Press a key to play",22,WHITE,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT*3/4)    
        pg.display.flip()
        start.any_key()#temporary key to start system.


    def any_key(wait):
        waiting = True
        while waiting:#a loop is used for the start screen until an action is done.
            wait.clock.tick(FPS)#allows animations to 
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:#if the 'x' button is pressed during the start screen.
                    waiting = False
                    wait.running = False#stops the main loop.
                if event.type == pg.KEYUP:#if any key is released.
                    waiting = False
    def over_screen(over):#displayed when the game ends.
        if not over.running:
            return#skips the over screen when 'x' button is pressed.
        over.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        over.draw_text('GAME OVER',48,WHITE,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT /4)
    def draw_text(self, text, size, color, x, y):

        font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)#selects the chosen font.
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)#creates the text with anti aliasing and the color chosen.
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x, y)#position of text.
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)#renders text on screen.

g = Game()
g.start_screen()
while g.running:#the main loop.
    g.new()
    g.over_screen()
pg.quit()#closes the window.
```

sprites:

```
#Sprite class
import random
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
vec = pg.math.Vector2 #creates a 2D Vector which stores the x an y cordinates for the sprites.
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):#create initialise the properties of the sprite.
        self.game = game#reference to variable in game class.
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)#provides functions for the sprite in other functions.
        self.image = pg.Surface((PLAYER_WIDTH,PLAYER_HEIGHT))#creates a square for the Player to be used as a hitbox.
        self.image.fill(GREEN)#place holder for the player.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2),(HEIGHT/4)# allows you to move the character.
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)#the center of the sprite.
        self.velocity = vec(0,0)#the speed of the player. 
        self.acceleration = vec(0,0)#allows for the change in speed.
        self.facing = 0 #direction the player is looking.
        self.current = 0#current direction facing.
        self.PLAYER_HEALTH = 1000
        self.bullet_list = []

    def jump(self):
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        if hits:#only able to jump when colliding with platform.
            self.velocity.y += -PLAYER_JUMP
        collide = hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.obstacles, False)
        if collide:
            self.velocity.y += -PLAYER_JUMP
    def shoot(self):
        #if game.cooldown > 400:
            #cooldown = 0
        self.bullet = Bullet(self,self.current,self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        self.bullet_list.append(self.bullet)
        for bullet in self.bullet_list:
            #self.bullet = Bullet(self.current,self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)#creates bullet postioned in center.
            self.game.all_sprites.add(self.bullet)
            self.game.bullets.add(self.bullet)
        #self.bullet = Bullet(self.current,self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)#creates bullet postioned in center.
        #self.game.all_sprites.add(self.bullet)
        #self.game.bullets.add(self.bullet)
    def update(self):
        self.acceleration = vec(0,PLAYER_GRAV)#resets the position of player when not moving.
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()#inputs a pressed key.
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.acceleration.x = -PLAYER_ACC
            self.facing = -1
        self.current = self.facing
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acceleration.x = PLAYER_ACC
            self.facing = 1
        self.current = self.facing

        if self.acceleration.x == 0:#if standing, the previous direction is saved
            self.facing = self.current
        #print(self.current)    
        #friction.
        self.acceleration.x += self.velocity.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
        #equation for displacment.
        self.velocity += self.acceleration
        self.pos += self.velocity + 0.5 * self.acceleration#moves thes players position to the new x,y co-ordinate.
        #boundaries of screen.
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH -(PLAYER_WIDTH * 0.5)#avoids overlapping the boundary.
            self.velocity.x = 0 #avoids player sticking to walls by capping speed at boundaries.
            self.acceleration.x = 0 #reduces the amount of 'jitter' when trying to move past boundaries.
        if self.rect.left < 0 :
            self.pos.x = (PLAYER_WIDTH * 0.5)#avoids overlapping the boundary.
            # have to add half the player width to avoid player going into walls.
            self.velocity.x = 0 #avoids player sticking to walls by stopping player at boundaries.



        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos#tracks the position of the players center.
class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite,):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
class Obstacle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.obs_health = 100
class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    damage = 25
    def __init__(self,player,current, x, y):
        self.player = player#allows the bullet class to use player variables.
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((20,10))
        self.image.fill(LBLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.right = x
        self.rect.centery = y + (PLAYER_HEIGHT/2)
        #self.damage = 25
        self.velocity = vec(0,0)
        if current == -1:#when looking left.
            self.velocity = vec(-10,0)
        if current == 1:#when looking right.
            self.velocity = vec(10,0)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.right += self.velocity.x
        #remove when moves of off screen.
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.kill()
            for bullet_amount in self.player.bullet_list:
                self.player.bullet_list.pop(self.player.bullet_list.index(bullet_amount))
        if self.rect.left <0:
            self.kill()
            for bullet_amount in self.player.bullet_list:
                self.player.bullet_list.pop(self.player.bullet_list.index(bullet_amount))
        #print(self.rect.x)
```

settings:

```
#settings
TITLE = "downpour"
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 60
FONT_NAME = 'Ariel'
#platforms 
PLATFORM_LIST = [(0, HEIGHT - 50, WIDTH, 50),
                 (WIDTH -225  ,HEIGHT * 3/4 -50,200, 40),#(x,y,width,height)of the platforms.
                 (0 +25 ,HEIGHT * 3/4 -50,200, 40),
                 (0 +350,HEIGHT * 3/4 -150,200, 40)]
OBSTACLE_LIST = [(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT -50-50,100,50),(WIDTH/3,HEIGHT -50-50,100,50),(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT -50-50,100,50)]
#player properties
PLAYER_WIDTH = 50
PLAYER_HEIGHT = 50
PLAYER_ACC = 0.55
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.05
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
PLAYER_JUMP = 15
#colors defines
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREY = (211,211,211)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
LBLUE = (132,112,255)
BGCOLOR = LBLUE
```

The problem I have encountered is with spawning a new box after destroying one of the multiple boxes. A box can be destroyed by depleting its health through shooting at it.

Lets say I have 3 boxes: A,B and C. when I try to destroy B or C, box A is the one that is destroyed and respawned.

I feel like it's an obvious answer...

code relating to the obstacle:

creating the class:

```
class Obstacle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.obs_health = 100
```

adding it to a Sprite group:

```
for obs in OBSTACLE_LIST:
            new.obstacle = Obstacle(*obs)
            new.all_sprites.add(new.obstacle)
            new.obstacles.add(new.obstacle)
```

collisions:

```
collide = pg.sprite.groupcollide(update.bullets,update.obstacles,True,False)
        if collide:

            update.obstacle.obs_health = update.obstacle.obs_health - bullet.damage
            if update.obstacle.obs_health == 0:
                update.obstacle.kill()
```

spawning a new obstacle:

```
while len(update.obstacles) < 3:
        width = random.randrange(50, 100)
        update.obstacle = Obstacle(random.randrange(0, WIDTH - width),HEIGHT-100,100,50)
        update.obstacles.add(update.obstacle)
        update.all_sprites.add(update.obstacle)
```

Comment: Maybe someone else will be able to help but at least I wasn't able to understand your question with my first read. Maybe it would help to explain your problem using specific names to identify boxes like follows: "When box A is destroyed, I want a different box B to spawn at a different location but instead the same box A spawns."

Comment: @KentShikama Thanks for the feedback! Reading over it again, I don't really clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for all instance methods, it would help the reader if you used the name `self` instead of all the custom names you're using such as `new` or `update` for the first argument.

After that rewrite, you code will look like follows:

```py
        collide = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets,self.obstacles,True,False)
        if collide:
            self.obstacle.obs_health = self.obstacle.obs_health - bullet.damage
            if self.obstacle.obs_health == 0:
                self.obstacle.kill()
```

Now ask yourself, why does the program know that the `self.obstacle` is the one that collided? Should `self.obstacle` even exist? It looks like `self.obstacle` was just used a temporary local variable upon creation of the Game class to add `Obstacle`'s to `self.obstacles`.

If so just use a local variable as follows:

```py
        for obs in OBSTACLE_LIST:
            obstacle = Obstacle(*obs)
            self.all_sprites.add(obstacle)
            self.obstacles.add(obstacle)
```

At this point, hopefully the error message will make it clear that referencing `self.obstacle` isn't going to work. `pg.sprite.groupcollide` returns you a `Sprite_dict`, so you need to extract the obstacle from `collide` to figure out what has collided.

Answer (score 0):

@KentShikama Thanks for pointing that out.

I have fixed the issue by using the dictionary.

```
for obstacles, bullets in collide.items():
            obstacles.obs_health = obstacles.obs_health - bullet.damage
            if obstacles.obs_health == 0:
                obstacles.kill()
```